# What driver is behind a certain device file?

Tags: linux, drivers, devices, block-device

Given a device file, say `/dev/sdb`, is it possible to determine what driver is behind it?

Specifically, I want to determine what driver my storage devices are using. `fdisk -l` lists 2 devices: `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`. One is a SATA hard drive and the other is a USB Mass Storage device - actually an SD card.

How do I determine, programmatically, which is which?

I am writing a piece of software, and I want to protect the beginner from obliterating their hard drives, whilst allowing them to obliterate their SD cards.

Comment: I assume you're running Linux, based on your choice of device name.

Comment: @Gilles Yeah, sorry that's probably quite an important piece of information... Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sda` and parse the output. You'll see lines like

```
DRIVERS=="ahci"
```

for a SATA disk using the `ahci` driver, or

```
DRIVERS=="usb-storage"
```

for an USB-connected device. You'll also be able to display vendor and model names for confirmation. Also,

```
ATTR{removable}=="1"
```

is present on removable devices.

All of this information can also be obtained through `/sys` (in fact, that's where `udevadm` goes to look), but the `/sys` interface changes from time to time, so parsing `udevadm` is more robust in the long term.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Sorry, yes, `-n` expects a path to a block device (something under `/dev`) whereas `-p` expects a path under `/sys` (e.g. `-p /sys/block/sda`).